# Setting the value of a static field using Reflection.Emit fails in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection.emit

I'm trying to set the value of a static field using `Reflection.Emit` (I don't have access to .NET 4's `Expression.Assign` because I'm stuck with Unity's .NET 3.5).

My current code is as follows:

```
public Action<TTarget, TField> GetSetter<TTarget, TField>(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
{
    DynamicMethod setterMethod = new DynamicMethod
    (
        "setter",
        typeof(void),
        new Type[] { typeof(TTarget), typeof(TField) },
        typeof(TTarget)
    );

    var setterIL = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();

    if (fieldInfo.IsStatic)
    {
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
    }
    else
    {
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    }

    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldInfo);
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return (Action<TTarget, TField>)setterMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TTarget, TField>));
}
```

And then, I invoke the setter using:

```
public class Static
{
    public static int x;
}

var fieldInfo = typeof(Static).GetField("x");

var setter = GetSetter<Static, int>(fieldInfo);

setter.Invoke(null, 123);
```

I get this error message:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   (wrapper dynamic-method) setter (...,int)

I thought loading null as the first argument (`Ldnull` opcode) would fix it, but it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** it seems the exception is only triggered when the code runs from within Unity (latest, 5.5.0p4). In a .NET 3.5 console application created from Visual Studio, there is no issue. Could there be an issue with Unity's Mono compiler?

Here is the full code to test from a `Tools > Debug IL` menu item in Unity.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using UnityEditor;

class Program
{
    public static Action<TTarget, TField> GetSetter<TTarget, TField>(FieldInfo fieldInfo)
    {
        DynamicMethod setterMethod = new DynamicMethod
        (
            "setter",
            typeof(void),
            new Type[] { typeof(TTarget), typeof(TField) },
            typeof(TTarget)
        );

        var setterIL = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();

        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldInfo);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        return (Action<TTarget, TField>)setterMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<TTarget, TField>));
    }

    public class Static
    {
        public static int x;
    }

    [MenuItem("Tools/Debug IL")]
    static void Debug()
    {
        var fieldInfo = typeof(Static).GetField("x");

        var setter = GetSetter<Static, int>(fieldInfo);

        setter.Invoke(null, 123);

        Debug.Log("Static field assignment succeeded.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code? `GetSetter<Static, int>` shouldn't compile - you can't use a static type as a type argument

Comment: Also, you don't need to check if the field is static or not. Since your method asks for the target, (and you provide it: `Invoke(null, 123)`) - you should simply always emit `Ldarg_0`. This also causes issue where someone writes `Invoke(notnullinstance, 123)` - which *should* throw an error, but would silently set `123` to the static field.

Comment: You're right, the class isn't static, I hastily put together a simplified example. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aya2tw8f(v=vs.100).aspx), you're right again, `Ldarg_0` should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: In that case I can't reproduce it (copy & pasted your code without changing) and it worked fine. What framework version are you running? Are you *sure* the field is indeed static?

Comment: I just copied and pasted exactly the example code I provided, and I get the error. I'm using .NET 3.5 inside Unity.

Comment: can't reproduce as well. Don't you build with mono?

Comment: I tested in a separate solution and I don't get the bug. In Unity, however, I get the exception. Updating the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Got it working with [`OpCodes.Stsfld`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.stsfld(v=vs.110).aspx) (set *static* field) instead:

```
if (fieldInfo.IsStatic)
{
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stsfld, fieldInfo);
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}
else
{
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldInfo);
    setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}
```

The .NET runtime is probably more lenient than the Mono runtime behind the scenes (i.e.: it allows `Stfld` even for a static field, just ignoring the first parameter, whereas Mono doesn't), which would explain why the issue only occurred in Unity.